# Match class name in SCSS

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I want to match some strings in my class name using mixin. It works without mixins, but when I used mixin, I can't pass the variable into the string.

**What was working**

```
div[class^='myclass-'], div[class*=' myclass-'] {
  @content
}
```

**What doesn't work**

```
@mixin startWith($name){
 div[class^=$name], div[class*=' ' + $name'] {
  @content;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your code. Use this

```
@mixin startWith($name){
 div[class^=$name], div[class*=$name] {
  @content;
 }
}
```

Comment: Error: Invalid CSS after "div[class^=": expected identifier or string, was "$name], div class..."

Comment: I have tested it with scss , it doesn't give any errors. Try on codepen